# Research areas in algebraic number theory

Tags: number-theory, soft-question, algebraic-number-theory

I am a graduate student and I intend to go on into research in Algebraic Number Theory. However, I would like to know what are the active areas of research and what kind of "flavour" they have.

I look forward to people's comments.

Comment: This would be a great question to ask a number theorist at your university.  Not only will you likely get a good answer, it may lead to further discussions, advising opportunities and so on.

Comment: @user600016 If you think my answer is useful I suggest you grab it whilst you can, as I'll be removing it tomorrow (Friday) as it's upsetting some of the moderators (who's views I actually agree with)